# Is vaping nicotine considered a violation of the fifth precept?

Tags: five-precepts

I understand that vaping nicotine is not a particularly healthy habit and is addictive. However, I’ve used it to quit smoking cigarettes and it has resulted in me abandoning them entirely, which I consider to be a huge milestone.

I also have a significant mental illness that I am very effectively managing with the help of medication and therapy. But I have read studies which suggest that nicotine can offer some psychological benefits for people with psychotic conditions like mine (I can offer a source for anyone interested), and I have found this to be true in my case.

Does vaping nicotine break the fifth precept?

Answer (score 2):

The translation of the fifth precept goes something like "these three fermented beverages cause heedlessness so I vow to abstain from them".  There's debate over what those three alcoholic beverages even are.  Were you the sleazy lawyer type, you could easily make the case that since whiskey wasn't known by the Buddha, surely it's not covered by the fifth precept!

But we're not sleazy lawyers.  We're siddhas, samanas, and so forth.  We're interested in what part of the precept will be most beneficial to our practice.  In this case, the whole precept hinges on that bit about causing heedlessness.  Does the substance you are imbibing make is less likely that you will follow the other precepts?  Will it interfere with your meditation?  Will it break your commitment to mindfulness.  If so, it's best avoided.

Specifically in your case, I would highly recommend that you maintain the nicotine habit until you reach a point where you can manage your symptoms without it.  Losing yourself to a psychotic episode is far more detrimental to your practice than pulling on a vape pen.  I wouldn't worry about it at all.

Answer (score 0):

The 5th precepts is about intoxicants that lead to heedlessness. In your situation, vaping nicotine does not break the fifth precept.

Answer (score 0):

You are worried about vaping but have you considered the situation of a Buddhist monks who doesn’t even have a pair of sandals to wear. Try to quit vaping as well unless it is necessary. I have quit alcoholism and I don’t drink at all. I eat bettle nuts though but I am not attached to it. I can live without bettle nuts as well. You should also have the same confidence. Do meditation on happiness. Be happy and make others happy without any external support. Intoxicants are no good.